# Regex: select html tag inside same html tag

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

I have this html text:

```
<blockquote>
    <blockquote>
        Children
    </blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

And I would like to match all the `<blockquote>` tags. I used this regex:

```
<blockquote>(.|\n)*?<\/blockquote>
```

And it works, even on multilines, but the match stops at the first `</blockquote>` closing, like in this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j04mc.png), while it should match the whole string.

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the question mark would match the whole string.

```
Old: <blockquote>(.|\n)*?<\/blockquote>
New: <blockquote>(.|\n)*<\/blockquote>
```